# Why can't I leave comments?

Tags: bug, comments, opera

Why can't I leave comments?

I think I have enough reputation. I using Opera 11; is this the problem?

Comment: We don't support very very very old browsers. You need to use something more modern.

Comment: @Oded that's versionism. Bigots.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - you are just jealous because our version is bigger than yours

Comment: @Oded version size is overrated. In my day, browsers were made with *passion*. Young people nowadays build them with all this cold, soulless technocracy - version control, A/B testing...

Comment: Never mind the version, feel the filesize.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The main site is practically dedicated to eradicating bugs, sheer entomonism... and you think SO cares about being called versionists? :-D

Comment: @S.L.Barth Calling something "Buggy" is pejorative and marginalizing in itself. The proper term is "functionally challenged"

Comment: By the way, just in case anyone is as slow as me, the OP is posting comments as answers *because they can't post comments, which is the whole point of this post*. It took me a while to understand :)

Comment: I do have to say I kind of sympathize with this request, but it's a cold hard world and the cost vs. benefit of supporting old browsers probably simply doesn't add up.

Comment: I think @Pekka웃 understands the problem well. You're asking for Stack Overflow to support old browsers. Supporting old browsers costs time. It costs the Stack Overflow developers time that they can use for other things. There are not many people who use old browsers - so it is not cost-effective for Stack Overflow to support old browsers.

Comment: Voting to leave open. The problem is real - not being able to comment is a serious hindrance. And not everybody has easy access to fast internet or big computers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Fast internet or big computers are not needed to run a supported browser. Also there are browsers and plugins that are designed to limit the amount of bandwidth used when on the internet.

Comment: Your profile says that you are proficient in JavaScript. Make a userscript to post the comments to the server. Should be rather straightforward.

Answer (score 20):

As was pointed out by @Oded, the browser you are using is not supported by Stack Exchange.
You don't want to use some of the officially supported browsers, because they take up too much memory. So I assume that, for whatever reason, you are using a small computer.

Stack Exchange has a [list of officially supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). Note that Opera 26 and 27 are on that list, as are browsers for some mobile devices.

You also mentioned that you don't want to download too much data. You could have a look at [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29), which is text-based. Note, however, that it is **not** on the list of supported browsers.

If you are using a mobile device, you could also see if the official Stack Exchange app can help you.

If there is no browser on the list that you want, then you could ask a question on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). The question would be, "what is a small-footprint browser that still allows me to post comments in Stack Exchange?"
I'm not active on Software Recommendations myself, but I believe that question should be specific enough to meet their criteria. (Please do read their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before asking).